# What is a dynamical symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, terminology, definition

What does the term [dynamical symmetry](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=definition&as_epq=dynamical+symmetry) refer to? Does it refer to the symmetry of the equation of motion? How is the symmetry of the equation of motion different from the form-variance of the equation of motion?

Answer (score 1):

Last time I read those words it was about the possibility of a baryodynamic field.
We know that Lagrangians in which a *global* gauge symmetry exists:
$$
\overline{\psi}\left(i\displaystyle{\not} \partial-m\right)\psi
$$
$$
\psi\mapsto e^{i\alpha}\psi
$$

are in principle amenable to a *local*-gauge generalisation along the lines of,
$$
\psi\mapsto e^{i\theta\left(x\right)}\psi
$$
We all know that you can arrange that by introducing the corresponding counter-terms in the way of gauge fields:
$$
A^{\mu}\mapsto A^{\mu}-i\partial^{\mu}\theta
$$
So people used to say things like "maybe the global symmetry can be raised to a dynamical symmetry." Meaning: "Maybe there is something like a baryo-dynamical field accounting for this symmetry."

But, of course, today we know gauge symmetries are not symmetries at all! Rather, they are ambiguities in the field definition. But old terminologies die hard.

I hope I didn't get it completely wrong, and you didn't mean something restricted to classical mechanics, but that's where I've definitely heard about those words. It was back in the 80's.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamical symmetries is term that has been used for a while now to mean various things.

In the modern context it refers to an algebraic relation for a quantum many-body system described by a Hamiltonian $H$,

$$[H,A]=\omega A,$$

where $A$ is an extensive operator, i.e. grows in norm with the volume of the system $||A|| \propto V$ and that has overlap with at least one strictly local observable $o(x)$, i.e $\langle o(x)A \rangle \neq 0$, where $\langle \rangle$ is the average.

The presence of such an algebra influences the statistical thermodynamic properties of the system, much like a standard symmetry influences them. For instance, think of how particle number conservation leads to a system thermalizing to a grand canononical state, instead of a canonical one, due to the additional Lagrange multiplier.

A system with a dynamical symmetry, will, instead of relaxing to stationary (time-independent) ensemble, display persistent time-dependence (non-stationarity) when it maximizes its entropy and will have a time-dependent Lagrange multiplier.

The importance of the requirement on extensivity and locality is rather technical, but can be understood via an analogy:
Take the eigenstates of a Hamiltonian $H|\psi_k\rangle=E_k |\psi_k\rangle$. Every thermodynamically large Hamiltonian has an infinite set of "symmetries", of the type $[H,|\psi_k\rangle\langle \psi_k |]=0$, but these are irrelevant for its long-time dynamics and equilibration. Only extensive ones, such as particle number, influence what kind of state the system will go into in the long-time limit. This is the origin of the extra requirements on the dynamical symmetries.

Some references:

1. [Non-stationary coherent quantum many-body dynamics through dissipation](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-09757-y)
2. [Isolated Heisenberg magnet as a quantum time crystal](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.102.041117)
3. [Rigorous bounds on dynamical response functions and time-translation symmetry breaking](https://scipost.org/SciPostPhys.9.1.003)
4. [Time Crystals Protected by Floquet Dynamical Symmetry in Hubbard Models](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.060601)